# Removing the iCloud back up message

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup, apple-id

I've been getting messages of the form

> **iPhone Not Backed Up**
>
> This iPhone hasn't been backed up in 141 weeks. Backups happen when this iPhone is plugged in, locked and connected to Wi-Fi.

I have the basic, free 5GB iCloud plan. I've turned off the storage for many apps, including Photos. Making my iCloud use only 594MB.

Is there a way to make it stop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable iCloud Backup in Settings → Apple ID → iCloud → iCloud Backup by switching the switch off.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks! They’re not going to message me about reactivating it now, right?

Comment: You now have no backup, so be careful. Your iPhone will be unrecoverable if lost or damaged.

Comment: @Brad Excellent point, but only if the OP isn't backing up to iTunes, which hopefully they're doing on a regular basis!